# All possible non decreasing sequence

Tags: algorithm

Consider the following code

```
double t0 = lower;
for(double t1 = t0; t1 < upper+0.2 ; t1 = t1 + 0.1){
            for(double t2 = t1; t2 < upper+0.2 ; t2 = t2 + 0.1){
            for(double t3 = t2; t3 < upper+0.2 ; t3 = t3 + 0.1){
                for(double t4 = t3; t4 < upper+0.2 ; t4 = t4 + 0.1){
                for(double t5 = t4; t5 < upper+0.2 ; t5 = t5 + 0.1){
                    bw.write(t0+"\t"+t1+"\t"+t2+"\t"+t3+"\t"+t4+"\t"+t5+"\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of having 5 nested loops if I were to take as parameter some k=5 which would output the same. I wish to compute such a sequence for any k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code wasn't exactly well explained, but the simplest approach is a recursive method:

```
void allPermutations(int k , double lower , double upper)
    double[] d = new double[d]
    d[0] = lower
    allPermutations(k - 1 , d , upper)

//k := number of elements that still need to be inserted into the permutation
void allPermutations(int k , double[] arr , double upper)
    if(k == 0)
        print(arr)
    else
        double lower = arr[length(arr) - k - 1]
        for(double d = lower ; d < upper + 0.2 ; d += 0.1)
            arr[length(arr) - k] = d
            allPermutations(k - 1 , arr)
```